# image map is working bad in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, image, dictionary

I want to publish image map in wordpress staticly, but it does not work, in the editor in admin panel and in pure html test it works,
is it because of css rules of the template?
What are the rules?

[test page](http://www.bezpkrk.ssd-linuxpl.com/podzial-krakowa-na-okregi-wyborcze/)

Comment: Where is the code you have already tried. It is hard to help when you don't know what to help with

Comment: it is standard image map (second image on the bottom) but it indicates wrong areas

Comment: it looks like the image has been postponed